# Вытащить кусок строки регуляркой

Tags: javascript

Совсем не знаком с регулярными выражениями. Нужна помощь

Есть строка "pot:HousingCooperative". Как с помощью регулярки получить только строку ":HousingCooperative"?

Comment: именно с двоеточием?

Comment: да, именно с двоеточием

Comment: зачем тут регулярка?

Comment: `':'+string.split(':').pop();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если условий больше нет, то подойдет такая регулярка

```
:\w+
```

[Пример](https://regex101.com/r/0lEuae/156)